# How to handle different actions of the same Controller in Express.JS?

Tags: node.js, express

I have many routes like:

```
//routes
app.get("page1/:action", function(req, res) {
  ...
}

app.get("page2/:action", function(req, res) {
  ...
}
```

where `page1` and `page2` are two controllers and the `:action` is the "method" I need to call. The pages should be:

1. /page1/delete
2. /page1/modify
3. /page1/add

I try to organize my code to simplify the job following a MVC system.
Could someone give me an advice regarding, how can I call the method of a controller by reading the parameter I use as `:action` I need to check if the method exists if not (if someone write `/page1/blablabla`) I return a 404 http error.

Thank you!

Comment: I would look into the [functions](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB) `app.get` `app.post` `app.put` `app.delete` which will make your interface more [RESTful](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Concept)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an example on how to achieve this. You can read more on this on the Expressjs guide: http://expressjs.com/guide/error-handling.html

```
function NotFound(msg){
  this.name = 'NotFound';
  Error.call(this, msg);
  Error.captureStackTrace(this, arguments.callee);
}
NotFound.prototype.__proto__ = Error.prototype;

//routes
app.get("page1/:action", function(req, res) {
  switch(req.params.action) {
    case 'delete':
      // delete 'action' here..
      break;
    case 'modify':
      // delete 'modify' here..
      break;
    case 'add':
      // delete 'add' here..
      break;
    default:
      throw new NotFound(); // 404 since action wasn't found
      // or you can redirect
      // res.redirect('/404');
  }
}

app.get('/404', function(req, res){
  throw new NotFound;
});
```

Comment: perfect! but Can I not optimize it? i mean something like: if (myController.{req.params.action}){ req.params.action()} else {throw new NotFound()} what do you think?

Comment: You can do something like: myController = ['delete', 'modify', 'add']; if (myController[req.params.action]) { ... } else { throw new NotFound() }

Comment: is there any specific reason why you don't want to confirm to REST design. e.g. Why not use http DELETE method to delete record ? See more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer